# How to replace every value in dataframe column to a corrected value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
car['Price'] = car['Price'].astype('string')
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('M', '*1000000', regex=True)
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('k', '*1000', regex=True)
correctVal = []
for x in car['Price']:
    x = pd.eval(x)
    correctVal.append(x)
```

I am having trouble on inserting all these x's back into the column of 'Price'. The column originally had Ms and Ks for millions and thousands which I wanted to transfer to actual numbers. I got the actual numbers, but keep getting errors when trying to put it back in the column.

I tried this but this only replaces the values with ONE number (the very last x from the for loop) :

```
car['Price'] = car['Price'].astype('string')
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('M', '*1000000', regex=True)
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('k', '*1000', regex=True)
for x in car['Price']:
    x = pd.eval(x)
    car['Price'] = x
```

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: The reason `car['Price']=x` fails is because car['Price'] is a column - so you're saying to assign the value "x" to the entire column, not just to a particular entry. Series.map() or Series.apply() should be used instead, as described by @scds below

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where using `map` seems simplest. It allows you to apply a function to every value in a specific column.

```
car['Price'] = car['Price'].astype('string')
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('M', '*1000000', regex=True)
car['Price'] = car['Price'].str.replace('k', '*1000', regex=True)

def fix_price(x):
    return pd.eval(x)

car["new_price"] = car["Price"].map(fix_price)
```

This assumes there are no missing values and everything is formatted as expected in the `Price` column. If not, you can add extra logic into the `fix_price` util to handle those cases.

Comment: Answer could be enhanced with a link to the map() function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html and possibly to its more-complex relative, apply(): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html